# what do you mean by registering a callback function in C?

Tags: c, callback

Can anyone please tell me,

- what exactly is meant by registering a callback function in C (with some examples)?
- what are Notify callbacks ?
- what are Asynchronous call backs?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a "callback" in C and how are they implemented?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/142789/what-is-a-callback-in-c-and-how-are-they-implemented)

Comment: See also, http://stackoverflow.com/a/147241/20270

Comment: the wikipedia page is decent http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_%28computer_programming%29

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2152974/interrupt-safe-way-to-set-function-pointer-in-hitech-c-on-pic32

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Registering a callback function simply means that you are arranging for an external entity to call your function.

It might happen at a later time, or it might happen straight away. A straightforward example is `qsort`. It is declared like this:

```
void qsort(void *base, size_t nel, size_t width,
       int (*compar)(const void *, const void *));
```

In order to use it, you must pass a pointer to a function that compares elements - the callback.

That was a simple example but generally "registering a callback" means passing a function pointer to someone who will call it for you in the future.

Answer (score 8):

**Registering a callback means to pass a function pointer to the one who will call your function through the pointer**

For easier understanding Consider A and B who are two entities involved in the code.
A has written a function say myFunc

```
char myFunc(int a)
{
/* Code written by A*/
}
```

Now when it is said A will register a callback with B, it means A will send the function pointer to B
By sending function pointer to B, A provides an access to the function

To register the callback there will be a function where A can pass the pointer
A will call the function as

```
cb_register(myFunc);
// Passed the address of Function
```

This cb_register function is defined in B as

```
typedef void (*cb_fn_ptr)(int a);

void cb_register(cb_fn_ptr cb)
{
    // In this function B can store the address in a structure member

}
```

For example a struct_B is declared which stores

```
struct s_B {
    cb_fn_ptr cb;
    // cb will have address whenever B 
};
```

B has stored the address (which the function pointer points to) and can use it to call the function later.

**When B calls the function through the function pointer it is called as callback.**
B just needs to know the prototype of the function to call the function and can be completely unaware of what the function does.
In this case function will call as

```
struct s_B temp;
char ret_val;
int arg_val;
ret_val = temp->cb(arg_val)
//This is a callback
```

Comment: how is the `cb_register` used and can we use callback without using a `struct`